# I can't upload a file to google cloud using python script?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am trying the python script available on GCP reference  to upload file to google cloud storage but every time I run it I get the error of file not found for the json key credential file even though it is in the same directory as the python script.

The error is :

> File "c:\users\kundan\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-
>   32\lib\site- 
>         packages\google\cloud\client.py", line 75, in from_service_account_json
>           with io.open(json_credentials_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as 
>       json_fi:
>         FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'key.json'

The code is as follows:

```
from google.cloud import storage

def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):

    storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(
    'key.json')
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)

    print('File {} uploaded to {}.'.format(
        source_file_name,
        destination_blob_name))

bucket='synersense_data'
source_file_name='gcp.txt'
destination_blob_name='prototype'

upload_blob(bucket,source_file_name,destination_blob_name)
```

Comment: Try adding absolute path to the `key.json` file.

Comment: same error even if I give the path as 'E:folder\file.json'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I used to upload a `abc.txt` file to google storage.

```
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('key.json')

def upload_blob(bucket_name, blob_name, filename):
    """ 
       Upload a blob to the bucket. 
       filename: source file name
       blob_name: destination blob name
    """
    bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)
    blob.upload_from_filename(filename)

print(upload_blob("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "temp/abc.txt", "abc.txt"))
```

And, below is the output:

[image]

Initially, I was also getting the same error as you were:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "gcp_upload.py", line 9, in
>   
>       client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('key.json')   File
>   "E:\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\client.py",
>   line 75, in from_service_account_json
>       with io.open(json_credentials_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as json_fi: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   'key.json'

I found the mistake I was making initially.

[image]

Check if the google storage credential json name is `key.json` or `key.json.json`. It might be possible that while renaming the original google storage credential json file, you named it `key.json`, but `.json` extension is automatically applied after renaming, so it would have been saved as `key.json.json` file, but you are passing `key.json` in `storage.Client.from_service_account_json()`(which actually needs to be `key.json.json`). Try checking it using `ls` or `dir` command.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Even though it was not the case it is working now. I am not getting the type of error.